# How to call the Publisher Methods in ASPBoilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am exploring the ASPBoilerplate framework and what interests me more is its real time notification capability. However, I am having this error.

Here is my Notification publisher class:

```
public class Publisher : Hub, ITransientDependency 
{
    private readonly INotificationPublisher _notificationPublisher;

    public Publisher(INotificationPublisher notificationPublisher)
    {
        _notificationPublisher = notificationPublisher;       
    }

    //Send a general notification to all subscribed users in current tenant (tenant in the session)
    public async Task Publish_Announcement(string announcementMessage)
    {
        //Example "LowDiskWarningMessage" content for English -> "Attention! Only {remainingDiskInMb} MBs left on the disk!"
        var data = new MessageNotificationData(announcementMessage);

        await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync("abp.notifications.received", data, severity: NotificationSeverity.Info);
    }

}
```

And I am testing if it will notify all online users whenever a new user was created.

```
    public override async Task<UserDto> Create(CreateUserDto input)
    {
        CheckCreatePermission();

        var user = ObjectMapper.Map<User>(input);

        user.TenantId = AbpSession.TenantId;
        user.IsEmailConfirmed = true;

        await _userManager.InitializeOptionsAsync(AbpSession.TenantId);

        CheckErrors(await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, input.Password));

        if (input.RoleNames != null)
        {
            CheckErrors(await _userManager.SetRoles(user, input.RoleNames));
        }

        CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();


       //I cannot call the publisher class since it has dependencies in its contructor.
        new Publisher().Publish_Announcement("Hi");

        return MapToEntityDto(user);
    }
```

Or am I just doing it wrong?
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: you need to inject Publisher. don't create it manually

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the Notifications is based on Publisher / Subsriber pattern and while the notifications are published through the system, the users who have subscribed to that notification will receive it.

**Publish Notifications**

```
public class MyService : ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly INotificationPublisher _notificationPublisher;

    public MyService(INotificationPublisher notificationPublisher)
    {
        _notificationPublisher = notificationPublisher;
    }

    //Send a general notification to a specific user
    public async Task Publish_SentFriendshipRequest(string senderUserName, string friendshipMessage, UserIdentifier targetUserId)
    {
        await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync("SentFriendshipRequest", new SentFriendshipRequestNotificationData(senderUserName, friendshipMessage), userIds: new[] { targetUserId });
    }

    //Send an entity notification to a specific user
    public async Task Publish_CommentPhoto(string commenterUserName, string comment, Guid photoId, UserIdentifier photoOwnerUserId)
    {
        await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync("CommentPhoto", new CommentPhotoNotificationData(commenterUserName, comment), new EntityIdentifier(typeof(Photo), photoId), userIds: new[] { photoOwnerUserId });
    }

    //Send a general notification to all subscribed users in current tenant (tenant in the session)
    public async Task Publish_LowDisk(int remainingDiskInMb)
    {
        //Example "LowDiskWarningMessage" content for English -> "Attention! Only {remainingDiskInMb} MBs left on the disk!"
        var data = new LocalizableMessageNotificationData(new LocalizableString("LowDiskWarningMessage", "MyLocalizationSourceName"));
        data["remainingDiskInMb"] = remainingDiskInMb;

        await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync("System.LowDisk", data, severity: NotificationSeverity.Warn);    
    }
}
```

**Subscribe to Notifications**

```
public class MyService : ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly INotificationSubscriptionManager _notificationSubscriptionManager;

    public MyService(INotificationSubscriptionManager notificationSubscriptionManager)
    {
        _notificationSubscriptionManager = notificationSubscriptionManager;
    }

    //Subscribe to a general notification
    public async Task Subscribe_SentFriendshipRequest(int? tenantId, long userId)
    {
        await _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeAsync(new UserIdentifier(tenantId, userId), "SentFriendshipRequest");    
    }

    //Subscribe to an entity notification
    public async Task Subscribe_CommentPhoto(int? tenantId, long userId, Guid photoId)
    {
        await _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeAsync(new UserIdentifier(tenantId, userId), "CommentPhoto", new EntityIdentifier(typeof(Photo), photoId));   
    }
}
```

**Client-Side**

This is done by `signalr` and you need to capture the event once it's triggered.

```
abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', function (userNotification) {
    if (userNotification.notification.data.type === 'Abp.Notifications.LocalizableMessageNotificationData') {
        var localizedText = abp.localization.localize(
            userNotification.notification.data.message.name,
            userNotification.notification.data.message.sourceName
        );

        $.each(userNotification.notification.data.properties, function (key, value) {
            localizedText = localizedText.replace('{' + key + '}', value);
        });

        alert('New localized notification: ' + localizedText);
    } else if (userNotification.notification.data.type === 'Abp.Notifications.MessageNotificationData') {
        alert('New simple notification: ' + userNotification.notification.data.message);
    }
});
```

You can find more information [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System)